# have trouble when use microsoft task api through OAuth2

Tags: oauth, microsoft-graph-api

I want to use microsoft task api in here `https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/previous-versions/office/office-365-api/api/version-2.0/task-rest-operations`. I understand if I want to request api I should use OAuth2. this is my OAuth steps:

step 1: register application in azure and config redirect uri ,then I can get client_id and new a client secret.
[image]

step 2: GET `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?client_id=<client_id>&redirect_uri=http://localhost:8080&response_type=code&scope=Tasks.Read`. now I can get code from redirect uri params: http://localhost:8080/?code=Mfcae1736-738e-3aff-2de6-7a6d72308feb#/login

step 3: POST `https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/v2.0/token` with params, like this:
[image]

step 4: from step 3 I can get access_token,(but It's not a jwt token, why?),so I can get tasks through access_token.
[image]

now there is a problem,the request return  wrong, but I don't know why, and don't where to find the correct doc and how to fix it .

```
{"error":{"code":"InvalidMsaTicket","message":"ErrorCode: 'PP_E_RPS_CERT_NOT_FOUND'. Message: ' Internal error:
spRPSTicket->ProcessToken failed. Failed to call CRPSDataCryptImpl::UnpackData: Internal error: Failed to decrypt data.
:Failed to get session key. RecipientId=293577. spCache->GetCacheItem returns error.:Cert Name: (null). SKI:
3bd72187c709b1c40b994f8b496a5b9ebd2f9b0c...'","innerError":{"requestId":"c6cec9b3-091f-439d-8e01-5489eef2b776","date":"2019-09-24T03:27:02"}}}
```

Comment: I have the same exact issue. Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Did you find a solution for this issue?